# Is it possible to display two views at the same time without switching option in view based application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to iOS programming and Xcode. I am doing a painter application via View based application in Xcode. Here I am going to draw in mainview and customize the settings in new view by click a button which is in mainview.

Whenver I click the button in mainview, it want to display a customize view in the mainview. mainview shouldnot be hidden. Customize view, it just a small view which display in mainview itself.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use this link [drawing rectangle on button click in viewcontroller class in objective c IOS5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527727/drawing-rectangle-on-button-click-in-viewcontroller-class-in-objective-c-ios5/10527872#10527872). I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: @laura: please try and tag questions properly in future - I've now tagged the question as `iOS`

Comment: @PaulR okay hereaftr i tag properly. can u tel how to upload my projct here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change view on button click in iPhone without navigation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619255/how-to-change-view-on-button-click-in-iphone-without-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Use like -

// Action on click of button -

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xpos, yPos, width, height]; //pass these values whatever you want
[mainView addSubView:newView];
```

// Now when you want to remove this -

```
[mainView removeFromSuperView:newView];
```

Comment: On the method which is called on button click.

Comment: What kind of help you needed, i can't write code for you? You need to tell the problem.

Comment: This is my code to switch main view to another view. but i need to display both the views in main view. by click a button view2 is to be display on mainvew.

 -(IBAction) SwitchTo2{
 [window setHidden:YES];
 [View2 setHidden:NO];
}

-(IBAction) SwitchTo1{
 [View2 setHidden:YES];
 [window setHidden:NO];